# how can i switch to another widget under the same mainwindow

Tags: qt, user-interface, pyqt

I want to change to another widget under the same `Mainwindow` when the `PushButton` is clicked. whether I need to create another py file? or create 2 widget in same class? thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best is to use a [QStackedLayout](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedlayout.html). This one can have many widgets attached but one and only one is used/displayed.

Example:

```
QMainWindow* wnd = new QMainWindow();
QWidget* centralWidget = new QWidget( wnd );
wnd->setCentralWidget( centralWidget );

QStackedLayout* layout = new QStackedLayout( centralWidget );
QLabel* label1 = new QLabel( "label1", centralWidget );
QLabel* label2 = new QLabel( "label2", centralWidget );
layout->addWidget( label1 );
layout->addWidget( label2 );

...
layout->setCurrentWidget( label1 ); // shows label1, hides label2

...
layout->setCurrentWidget( label2 ); // shows label2, hides label1
```